# How to avoid rebuilding in targets with different names in Windows and Linux?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have this in my makefile

```
myfile: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

This should convert into something like

```
g++ -o myfile XXX.o YYY.o ZZZ.o
```

But this generates different output in Windows and Linux

**Windows:** myfile.exe

**Linux:** myfile.out

So when I run `make` again, it will rebuild (even if there's no changes), because the target name is `myfile` and not `myfile.exe` or `myfile.out`. Of course I tried using `myfile.exe` as target name on Windows, and it shows the *up to date* or *nothing to do* message I want.

How can I solve this problem so that Make finds `myfile.exe|out` and decides to not rebuild it?

Comment: Um, you need to rebuild everything if you are building on or for  a different operating system.  Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Yes of course, but if I rebuild again in that same platform, it will rebuild again without the `up to date` thing.

Comment: On `Linux` that should produce just `myfile` not `myfile.out` is that your exact makefile entry?

Comment: @Galik regardless of what Linux produces, on Windows it will always rebuild it because it only expects `myfile.exe` and not anything else

Comment: Which compilation system are you using on Windows.

Comment: I'm using MinGW and I use `mingw32-make` to execute Make.

Comment: Define two targets, myfile.exe and myfile.out, and then build them by executing `make myfile.exe` _or_ `make myfile.out`. Or simply let myfile.exe be the name of the Linux target, too (it is perfectly ok, as Linux couldn't care less about the extension of the executable file).

Comment: The way I do it is to have two separate top-level targets `win` and `lin`, and define names of executables, libraries and whatnot depending on what I'm building for.

Comment: Yeah those are nice solutions, thanks!

Comment: You can also look at passing `-MP -MD` as compiler options to add a phony target for each dependency (other than the main file) to trigger rebuild of only the targets that need to be updated (see `man gcc`). I haven't checked mingw, but don't see why it would not be supported)

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no way that makefile generates `myfile.out` on Linux.

Comment: @MadScientist you can generate a `.out` by specifying that extension. So there's a way, just to be clear. (Anyway, I was on Windows at the moment of writing this question so I couldn't double check)

Comment: Sure.  But _that_ makefile, that you show, doesn't create `myfile.out`.  In UNIX systems GCC always generates exactly the file that you asked for with `-o`, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

GCC on Windows will automatically append .exe to the output filename when linking, try something like

```
ifneq ($(findstring mingw,$(MAKE_HOST)),)
exe := .exe
endif

myfile$(exe): $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

Or as the comments say just use .exe for all platforms.